# Count columns in a table where columns are same and then subtract from a column in another table

Tags: sqlite

Lets pretend that we have a supermarket.
We got a table called Sales where every record is one article), so if we scan 3 articles we will have 3 rows with following columns: ArticleId and Amount where amount Always is 1.
And then we have a table called Articles which have columns: ArticleId and AvailableAmount.

When the sale is done we need to Count records that are the same in Sales table and then update AvailableAmount with AvailableAmount subtracted with the sum of each article.

I'm thinking something like this but i dont know if im thinking right:

```
UPDATE Articles
SET
   AvailableAmount = AvailableAmount - (
      Select ArticleId,Count(*) From Sales Group by ArticleId HAVING Count(*) > 1
   )
WHERE 
ArticleId in(Select distinct ArticleId FROM Sales)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query is almost correct, but

1. the subquery must return only one column,
2. `HAVING Count(*) > 1` does not make sense, and
3. the subquery must return only one value, so you need a [correlated subquery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery):

   ```
   UPDATE Articles
   SET AvailableAmount = AvailableAmount -
           (SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM Sales
            WHERE ArticleId = Articles.ArticleId)
   WHERE ArticleId IN (SELECT ArticleId
                       FROM Sales)
   ```